# Power BI DAX - MAX of COUNT strings vs numbers

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

My current mesure for "Orders" elects the MAX of the MAX of two number values.

[image]

```
Range MAX Orders = MAXX(
    {
        Max(Ziele[ScopeOrd]),
        MAX(Ist[Orders])
    },
    [Value]
)
```

The Result is correct = **35**

My problem is, that for my "Company" mesure I have the string Names of the companies and the numbers for my scope.

[image]

So I guess that I need to create a count mesure first, but it should still be in the context of the countries. Or is it possible to put all in one?

I have tried:

```
Range MAX Orders = MAXX(
    {
        Max(Ziele[ScopeComp]),
        MAX(COUNT(Ist[Company]))
    },
    [Value]
)
```

Unfortunatly that results in an error:

```
The MAX function only accepts a column reference as an argument.
```

Please let me know how to solve it best.

Here is some example data.
Table Ist:
**Company|ISO2**
Acme Corporation|US
Globex Corporation|US
Soylent Corp|DE
Initech|DE
Umbrella Corporation|IT
Hooli|US
Vehement Capital Partners|US

Table Ziele:
**ScopeComp|ISO2**
2|US
3|DE
2|IT

The Result for the exampe data should be = 4
Since there is a COUNT of 4 companies in the US and this is greater then the number 3 MAX of the ScopeComp.

Comment: Can you please provide reprex, with sample data, and desired results?

Comment: Sample data and the expected result was added to the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Range MAX Orders = 
VAR Tbl = MAXX(ADDCOLUMNS(
            VALUES(Ist[ISO2]),
            "TCount",CALCULATE(COUNT(Ist[ISO2]))
),[TCount])
VAR Tbl2 = MAX(Ziele[ScopeComp])
RETURN
    MAXX(
        {Tbl,Tbl2},[Value])
```

If we test it on a visual card,

[image: Final]

Comment: There is some kinda genius on the run. It works perfektly! The logic is a bit hard to understand. But thank you very mutch.

Comment: You're welcome! Pleased to hear that your problem is solved.